# Angular : [Object Object]

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm working on a NodeJS/Angular project and while trying to do a simple CRUD, I'm blocked when I try to get an element by ID.
I would like to retrieve all the info of a "Member" based on its ID and display the info in a table. I manage to get my JSON with the API call but when trying to display it in the table, it doesn't show anything.

My service, with the API call :

```
    public getMember(id: number) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(this.config.apiServer + `astreintes/member/get/${id}`)
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    resolve(res as Member);
                    console.log(res);
                }, err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }
```

Result of the console.log: My correct JSON with the info of the member

My component.ts :

```
public search(){
  this.memberService.getMember(this.id).then((data) => {
    if(data){
              this.member = (data as any).recordset;
              console.log("Get member :"+ data);
              this.indice = true;
            }else{
              }},
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }                                                   
  );
}
```

Result of the console.log: "Get member : [Object Object]"

For the interface, I just have a dropdown list of all my members, and when I select one and click on the button "Search", it gets the info of my member correctly in the console. Then, I want to display it in my table below. My html code:

```
<form (submit)='search()' #searchMemberForm="ngForm"  class="form-horizontal">
      <select [(ngModel)]="id" name="member">
        <option *ngFor="let member of membersList" 
          [value]="member.Id_OnCall_Member">{{member.Oncall_Member_Name}}</option>
        </select>

 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-save btn-primary">Search</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>

<div *ngIf="indice">
<h1 style="text-align: center">
  Informations
</h1>
<table  class="table table-striped" *ngIf="indice">
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Nom</th>
  <th>Numéro de téléphone</th>
  <th>Statut d'activité</th>
    <tr *ngFor="let m of member">
      <td>{{m.Id_OnCall_Member}}</td>
      <td>{{m.Oncall_Member_Name}}</td>
      <td>{{m.OnCall_Member_Phone}}</td>
      <td>{{m.OnCall_Member_Status}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you tell us what gets actually rendered in the dom (via Chrome developer tools)?

Comment: do a console log with JSON.stringify so you don't get [object Object] and you will see what you have there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answers.
My problem wasn't the console.log though, it was just an indication.

My real problem was that it didn't show anything in my table. But I solved it, here's how in case it might help other people.

In my component.ts, I replaced:
 `this.member = (data as any).recordset;`
By this, simply:
`this.member = data;`

Answer (score 4):

you used "+" in console.log:  console.log("Get member :"+ data);

it means javascript is trying to convert the output to one type (string), but data is object. Below you can find how to get the correct output.

```js
const res = {
 memberId: 1
}

console.log(res) // {memberId: 1}

console.log('Member: '+ res); //Member: [object Object]

console.log('Member: ', res); // Member: {memberId: 1}

console.log('Member: '+ JSON.stringify(res)); // Member: {memberId: 1}
```